# PHPSESSID - Problems setting time expiration (PHP 5.5.9 in Ubuntu)

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, samesite

Version -> PHP 5.5.9

I'd started to develop some programs and I'd noticed that the session expired really fast, in 15 minutes but I'd set it to 24 hours.

After checking the web console in firefox, I read some warning messages:

*Cookie "PHPSESSID" will be soon rejected because it has the "sameSite" attribute set to "none" or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the "sameSite" attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies*

After reading a lot of stuff and feel like an absolute ignorant, I'd started to see the light.

The regular cookies, now are set with a little (and ugly) hack:

```
function setcookiefix($name, $value) {
    $cookie_time = time() + 3600 * 24;
    setcookie($name, $value, $cookie_time, '/; samesite=lax');
}
```

That allows me to create the cookies lax, but I cannot do it with the PHPSEESID cookie and that expires all my cookies in 15 minutes if I don't do any call to the server.

How can I fix it? TIP -> I can't update the PHP version, that's a fight vs the ancient servers... ;)

I'll try to extend it as I did all this years but ignores this commands:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", 3600 * 24); //24 horas
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600 * 24); //24 horas
session_set_cookie_params(3600 * 24, "/");
session_start();
```

Thanks for your help and time.

Best regards,

Pablo.

Comment: After you use ini_set, use ini_get to check if the value gets saved. So we can go deeper into the problem.

Comment: After executing the ini_get for both values, they return 86400 for both.